# show default value on group button function

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
$(function() {

  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    //hide all sections
    $(".content-section").hide();
    //show the section depending on which button was clicked
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-section")).show();
  });

});
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
  <button type="button" data-section="section1" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton ">Section1</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section2" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section2</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section3" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section3</button>
</div>

<div class="content-section" id="section1">
  <h1> Section 1 </h1>
  <p>Section 1 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section2">
  <h1> Section 2 </h1>
  <p>Section 2 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section3">
  <h1> Section 3 </h1>
  <p>Section 3 Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

i have this group button function as you can see it always hide all display value by default  but i want section 1 display block to show it's value by default without me click at it  when i opened this page and ofcourse it will hide and open later when i select another button or select it.iam realy newbie to this so how i can archive something like that in this code?.

Comment: why don't u use this '$( ".btn" ).trigger( "click" );'

Comment: with out change u r code just put it on u r script,  i'm sure it's will be works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

One simple way can be, to auto click on the first button **AFTER the `click` event binding**. Like this:

`$(".btn").first().click()`

[`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) selects the first button

[`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) triggers the same event that you have bound in `.on`

```js
$(function() {

  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    //hide all sections
    $(".content-section").hide();
    //show the section depending on which button was clicked
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-section")).show();
  }).first().click();

});
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
  <button type="button" data-section="section1" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton ">Section1</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section2" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section2</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section3" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section3</button>
</div>

<div class="content-section" id="section1">
  <h1> Section 1 </h1>
  <p>Section 1 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section2">
  <h1> Section 2 </h1>
  <p>Section 2 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section3">
  <h1> Section 3 </h1>
  <p>Section 3 Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

---

**Method 2:**

**Another way can be:** Add an `active` class to show the selected tab content. On click just toggle the `active` class to show/hide the content of the tab. You can add `active` class to any tab content that you want to show as default in the HTML, to start with. (Here I have added `active` class in the 1st tab content)

```js
$(function() {

  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    //hide all sections
    $(".content-section").removeClass('active');
    //show the section depending on which button was clicked
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-section")).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}
.content-section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
  <button type="button" data-section="section1" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton ">Section1</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section2" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section2</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section3" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section3</button>
</div>

<div class="content-section active" id="section1">
  <h1> Section 1 </h1>
  <p>Section 1 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section2">
  <h1> Section 2 </h1>
  <p>Section 2 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section3">
  <h1> Section 3 </h1>
  <p>Section 3 Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    //hide all sections
    $(".content-section").hide();
    //show the section depending on which button was clicked
    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-section")).show();
  });
  $(".btn").first().trigger("click");
});
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
  <button type="button" data-section="section1" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton ">Section1</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section2" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section2</button>
  <button type="button" data-section="section3" class="btn btn-primary segmentedButton">Section3</button>
</div>

<div class="content-section" id="section1">
  <h1> Section 1 </h1>
  <p>Section 1 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section2">
  <h1> Section 2 </h1>
  <p>Section 2 Content goes here</p>
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="section3">
  <h1> Section 3 </h1>
  <p>Section 3 Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".btn").trigger("click");` should be after the `.on` event. Also it will trigger click on all the buttons.

Comment: class base click event not working using trigger('click') @HimanshuTyagi

Comment: You need to add `$(".btn").first().trigger("click");` after the `$(".btn").on(..);` then it will work. Notice the `.first()` to slect only the first btn.

Comment: i try both method from you and @Himanshu Tyagi both of it work but curently i used a method 2 from Himanshu Tyagi this is more simple just change few changes on html and ccss. but ty for ur answer sir.